# How to put every new input into a new list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want it to be so that once the user input's their inputs, they both will go into a new list.

```
num = int(input("Choose a number"))

for i in range(num):
    input1, input2 = input("").split()
```

For each input1 and input2, I want it go into an entirely new list. For example:
If I input num as 3, I would have to input, input1 and input 2, three times. I want three different lists then for that case containing just input 1 and input2.

```
Input: 
>> Choose a number 3
>> 4 5
>> 3 6
>> 2 2

Output: 
>> [4,5] 
>> [3,6]
>> [2,2]
```

Just to clarify, the "choose a number" input is entirely based on input. This means that "x" number of lists should be created with input1 and input2 based on the choose a number input (x)

Comment: so you want to assign the each list to different variable ?

Comment: Yes, for each input1 and input2, I want it to go to a new list. So that when I call that list, it should only display those inputs.

Comment: so what about when you have 100 list you want to call them different name ?

Comment: Yes. If that is possible.

Comment: better to use dictionary or  list of list to this purpose and access them by there key  and index value respectively

Comment: I'm voting to close this, I don't see the benefit of these kinds of basic/trivial questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can use list of lists to store the results:

```py
num = int(input("Choose a number"))
res = [] # this will store all user inputs.
for i in range(num):
    input1, input2 = input("").split()
    res.append([input1, input2])

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

output

```
Choose a number 3
 5 2
 4 2
 6 56
['5', '2']
['4', '2']
['6', '56']
```

- solution 2:

```py
num = int(input("Choose a number"))
res = dict() # this will store all user inputs.
for i in range(num):
    res['user'+str(i)] = input("").split()
print(res['user1'])
```

- output:

```
Choose a number 3
 2 5
 2 5
 36 663
['2', '5']
```

Comment: is it possible to be able to have each of them in a seperate list? So when i call a certain list it will only print those inputs?

Comment: For that you need to use `dictonary` like structure.

Comment: Thanks! I think the solution 2 is what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way, for example:

```
num = int(input("Choose a number"))

temp = []
for _ in range(num):
    input1, input2 = input().split()
    temp.append([input1, input2])
    print(temp); temp = []
```

Comment: I have a question, why would you do mod 3?

Comment: @Sar17 Sorry, it was a mistake.

Comment: You dont need to write `str` for input. They are already strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a main list, then add your sublist (splitted input) into it :

```
num = int(input("Choose a number"))
values = []
for _ in range(num):
    values.append(input("").split())

print(values) # [[4,5], [3,6], [2,2]]
print(values[1]) # [3,6]
```

Using a list-comprehesion, the same is

```
values = [input("").split() for _ in range(num)]
```

Do the following, to get each sublist on a new line

```
print(*values, sep='\n')
```

Comment: You should use `_` instead of `i` if you are not using it.